# choosing names regarding iterators

Tags: python-3.x

I have a general question when it comes to choosing names for iterators:
i have a class "A" with method "onemethod":
does it matter if i use the same name for an iterator in a list comprehension?
for example will this give me problems?:

```
def onemethod(self):
    self.firstlist = [i for i in bla]
    self.secondlist = [i*2 for i in bla]
    self.thirdlist = [a*i for i in range(10)]
```

meaning, if i use "i" as an iterator in every list comprehension of this method, will this be a problem at some point ?

Answer (score 1):

It won't be a problem as long as you don't expect `i` to have any specific value *outside* those list comprehensions and generator expressions.

I'd argue that it's a good practice to not assume it even *exists* outside those contexts (even though it does).

Comment: Python 2.x use to leak its scope for list-comps - so it could lead to some interesting happenings... but if `i` doesn't exist in scope outside of the comprehension scope, it won't exist... (eg - in Python 3.x, it's a proper enclosure)

Comment: not existing outside the comprehensions scope, does that mean something like "self.i"? I allways thought that in python 3 names without "self." infront of them can´t be accessed outside the method, or am i wrong ?